# I don't have a clear understanding of the relationship between area and the integral.

Tags: calculus

I don't have a clear understanding of the relationship between area and the integral.  I mean the nuts and bolts issues though I understand that the area under the curve of f(x) is given by its definite integral and that the areas above x-axis are taken +ve and those below -ve.  My question is if we interchange the limits the answer changes the sign.  The area remains above or below the x-axis.  Why the answer is changing the sign>?  Obviously, I am missing something important here.  Kindly help.  Also want to understand the principles clearly without much of maths.  Plan is to once I understand the principles, I can get into the details of Lebesgue and other matters later.  First I want to know the motivations and principles of positive and negative areas.

Comment: Because Riemann sums are actually over *oriented* intervals in $\Bbb R$.  When you get to Lebesgue integrals you'll see what it means to integrate over an *unoriented* interval.

Comment: So to say that curves above x-axis are +ve and others are -ve, is it oversimplification?

Comment: positive is +ve. negative is -ve.

Comment: Because the $\Delta x$ in the sum switches signs.

Comment: @user3141822 No, "+ve" is *not* "positive", it's a weird thing that should never be written.

Comment: Why weird?  It is most commonly used.  Just shorthand for positive and negative.  Nothing more or less than that.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

[Why does an integral change signs when flipping the boundaries?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1316529/why-does-an-integral-change-signs-when-flipping-the-boundaries)

The answers there are in greater detail than I could provide. It might be helpful to decouple the notions of integral and area; that is, the integral of a curve happens to be the area under the curve, but is not defined by it.