# Show that $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^{n}x^ \,dx = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^{n}x^ \,dx$

Tags: integration

Given that $n$ is a positive integer, show that $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^{n}x^ \,dx = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^{n}x^ \,dx.$$

I know how to use integration by parts but I am not sure how can I apply that to show that this can be solved using that method. Please help me determine the steps on how can I easily prove this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If $f$ is any function defined on $[0,1],$ $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} f(\sin x)\,dx=\int_0^{\pi/2} f(\cos x)\,dx.$$ You don’t need to evaluate the integral to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Note that $\cos x=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)$, hence $$\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\cos^n x\,dx=\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\sin^n\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)\,dx$$

Now, consider the substitution $u=\frac{\pi}{2}-x$.

Comment: This is what I got.
$-\int^{0}_{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^n u\,du$

Comment: Don't forget that $\frac{du}{dx}=-1$, so you should have a minus sign somewhere, and you shouldn't be getting a $\cos^n$ term.

Comment: Nice, now you should [swap bounds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1688872/understanding-of-swapping-bounds-of-integral) which should give you the desired answer.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance, however, the end result was in terms of $u$, not in $x$

Comment: You're integrating the same function over the same bounds on both sides of the equality so they are the same. If you remain unconvinced then you could apply the substitution $x=u$ (though if you do that then it feels like overloading a variable...)