# Show that integral of even $\times$ odd = 0, even $\times$ even is not necessarily zero

Tags: integration, functions, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I am doing a fourier series example, and the solution contains of a somewhat surprising claim.

Let $f(t)$ be a real-valued, even function, that is, $f(t) = f(-t)$.

Then

$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) (\cos(\omega t) + i\sin(\omega t)) \mathrm{dt} = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) \cos(\omega t) \mathrm{dt} $$

Because "**even  $\times$ odd = 0, even $\times$ even is not necessarily zero**"

Is there a way to justify the above explanation?

Comment: You don't even need to consider infinite integrals. Using your even function $f$, $$\int_{-a}^a f(t)\,\mathrm dt=\int_{-a}^0 f(t)\,\mathrm dt+\int_0^a f(t)\,\mathrm dt=2\int_0^a f(t)\,\mathrm dt$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is even and $g$ is odd, then $h := f \cdot g$ is also odd, so its integral over an interval $[-T,T]$ is zero.
$$\int_{-T}^Th(t) \mathop{dt} = \int_0^Th(t) \mathop{dt} + \int_{-T}^0 h(t) \mathop{dt} =  \int_0^T h(t) \mathop{dt}-  \int_0^T h(t) \mathop{dt} = 0 $$
Here, $g(t) = i \sin (\omega t)$.

---

If $f$ is even and $g$ is even, then $f \cdot g$ is also even, and all we can say is
$$\int_{-T}^T h(t) \mathop{dt} = 2 \int_0^T h(t) \mathop{dt}.$$
Here, $g(t) = \cos(\omega t)$.

---

In response to your comment: in general ($h$ doesn't have to be odd or even), we have
$$\int_{-T}^0 h(t) \mathop{dt} = -\int_T^0 h(-u) \mathop{du} = \int_0^T h(-u) \mathop{du}.$$
When $h$ is odd, then this becomes $- \int_0^T h(u) \mathop{du}$. When $h$ is even, this becomes $\int_0^T h(u) \mathop{du}$. I used these facts in my above computations.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but isn't $\int_{-T}^T h(t) \mathop{dt} = \int_0^T h(t) \mathop{dt} +  \int_{-T}^0 h(t) \mathop{dt}  =  \int_0^T h(t) \mathop{dt} -   \int_0^T h(t) \mathop{dt}  = 0$  since https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1316529/why-does-an-integral-change-signs-when-flipping-the-boundaries

Comment: @StackexchangeHouseNinja See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can consider integral on $(-\infty,0)$ and $[0,+\infty)$

Comment: I don't think this is enough information to be a hint. Can you expand your answer a bit more?