# Generalization of the derivative of accumulation function: 1st fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

The 1st fundamental theorem of calculus:
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \left[\int_a^x f(t)\,dt) \right]=f(x),\qquad x \in (a,b).
$$
No textbook says that this can be generalized into the scenario where $x$ is less than $a$ and where $f$ is continuous for $x<a$. In fact, $x$ can be anything other than $a$, as long as $f$ is continuous in the regions in question. Why is this not generalized in any textbook?

Comment: 1) maybe $f$ is defined sometimes only in $(a,b)$. 2) even if $f$ is defined everywhere, it's barely a generalization. for example, if $x < a$, then, for any $c < x$, $\int_a^x f(t)dt = -\int_x^a f(t)dt = \int_x^a -f(t)dt = \int_c^a -f(t)dt - \int_c^x -f(t)dt$, so $\frac{d[\int_a^x f(t)dt]}{dx} = -\frac{d[\int_c^x -f(t)dt]}{dx} = -(-f(x)) = f(x)$. even though I wrote a lot, all that is happening is that instead of being in $(a,b)$, you're in $(c,a)$ for some $c < x$.

Comment: @mathworker21 thank you for the feedback, I have deleted the answer below. But if you could tell me what is wrong it would be nice. What is wrong with saying that the generalization is not done because it is not useful? If I am sounding stupid , then tell me , but also tell me why, because I don't want to repeat mistakes, a grave one sensing from your reaction. I am still learning,my reputation does not reflect that.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг 1). (minor point) the question is "how much should i generalize" rather than "how much do i generalize". 2). (real issue) the OP was asking about $\int_a^x$ for $x < a$, not for $\int_T^x$ for $T \in (a,b)$ and $x > T, x \in (a,b)$. I mean, your whole answer seems to be a red herring.

Comment: @mathworker21 thank you for that, I will be much much more careful next time.

Comment: Thank you all. I can't accept any comments unless they are put as answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bold claim that *no textbook* contains the desired generalization, but I am inclined to agree with you as I have never seen one.

The reason for this "omission" is simple: The (Riemann) integral $\int_a^b f(t)dt$ is defined for functions $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ on an interval $[a,b]$, and here we have $a < b$.

If we critically examine this construction, we see that in most textbooks not even $\int_a^a f(t)dt$ is defined, and this integral is needed in order that
$$F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)dt$$
is well-defined for $x = a$. It seems that most authors tacitly assume that $\int_a^a f(t)dt = 0$ which is of course justified. In a few textbooks it is essentially covered by the the general construction of the integral if we agree to consider $[a,a]$ as a (degenerate) interval. An example is "Baby Rudin": A partition of an interval $[a,b]$ is a finite sequence of points $x_i$ such that $a = x_0 \le x_1 \le \ldots \le x_{n-1} \le x_n = b$. Working with this concept we see that $\int_a^a f(t)dt = 0$. However, in most textbooks it is required that $a = x_0 < x_1 < \ldots < x_{n-1} < x_n = b$, hence $\int_a^a f(t)dt$ is not covered by the construction, and then $\int_a^a f(t)dt = 0$ becomes a *definition*. There are good reasons to do so.

1. For all $v \in (u,w)$ we have $$(*) \quad \int_u^w f(t)dt = \int_u^v f(t)dt + \int_v^w f(t)dt .$$ This generalizes to all $v \in [u,w]$ iff we set $\int_a^a f(t)dt = 0$.
2. The above function $F : (a,b] \to \mathbb R$ is continuous. We have $\lim_{x\to a} F(x) = 0$, thus a continuous extension to $[a,b]$ is obtained iff we set $F(a) =  0$.

We now come to your question. Integrals of the form $\int_c^d f(t)dt$ for $c > d$ are not considered in many textbooks, and thus it is no surprise that your generalization does not occur.

Of course, one usually *defines* $$(**) \quad \int_c^d f(t)dt = - \int_d^c f(t)dt. $$ This has good reasons. In fact, we want that $(*)$ is satisfied for all $u,v,w$ in the interval on which $f$ lives, and this enforces $(**)$. See for example
[Why does an integral change signs when flipping the boundaries?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1316529/why-does-an-integral-change-signs-when-flipping-the-boundaries) It has also a nice intuitive interpretation. If we integrate from $d$ to $c$, then we go in positive direction from $d$ to $c$ and any partition $P = (x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ of $[d,c]$ produces the factors $d_i =(x_{i+1}-x_i)$ in the Riemann sum. If we do it in the other direction, we get the factors $(x_i - x_{i+1}) = -d_i$. This leads to a change of sign of the whole Riemann sum.

For any integrable function $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ and any $r \in [a,b]$ we can now define $$F_r : [a,b] \to \mathbb R, F_r(x) = \int_r^x f(t)dt .$$

For a continuous $f$ we then we have $F_r'(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ (see  mathworker21's comment). In fact this is a *trivial generalization* of the standard theorem which says that $F'_a(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. Simply note that $F_r(x) = F_a(x) - F_a(r)$.