# Does interchanging the derivative and integral apply for $G’(x)=\frac{d}{dx} \Big{(}\int_{1}^{e^x}\frac{1}{1+log(t)}dt \Big{)}?$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, derivatives, definite-integrals

**Question**

I am looking to differentiate the following integral with respect to $x$ (for $x>0$):

$$G(x)=\int_{1}^{e^x}\frac{1}{1+log(t)}dt$$

**Attempt**

I know that I can bring the derivative inside of the integral if the inside function and its partial derivative are continuous within the limits.

My only hesitation in this case, is if this proposition still applies to the case where the limits are functions of variables.

If so, does that make the derivative of $G(x)$ simply:

$$G'(x)=\int_{1}^{e^x}0dt=0$$

Since the derivative of the inside with respect to $x$ is $0$ (as it is constant with respect to $x$). Or am I misunderstanding something?

It doesn't feel like this can be the correct answer to the problem, so I would be grateful for any clarification.

Comment: Try combining the FTC1 with the chain rule.

Comment: Thanks. What is the reason for not being able to apply my idea of bringing the derivative into the integral? @ryang

Comment: But the procedure involves differentiating $e^x,$ not that fractional integrand, right?

Comment: So the answer would end up being $\frac{e^x}{1+x}$ using the FTC and the chain rule? My answer seems to differ from the one posted below. Unless differentiating that answer leads to my answer @ryang

Comment: Indeed, [$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \left(\frac1e\left(\operatorname{Ei}(1+x)-\operatorname{Ei}(1)\right)\right)=\frac{e^x}{1+x}.$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=d%2Fdx%281%2Fe%28Ei%281%2Bx%29-Ei%281%29%29%29) -)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, that makes a lot more sense now @ryang

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I know that I can bring the derivative inside of the integral if the inside function and its partial derivative are continuous within the limits.

What you're quoting here is [Differentiation under the integral sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), formally stated as:

"Let $f(x,t)$ be a function such that both $f(x,t)$ and its partial derivative $f_x(x, t)$ are continuous in $t$ and $x$ in some region of the $xt$-plane, including $a(x)\leq t\leq b(x)$, $x_0\leq x\leq x_1$. Also suppose that the functions $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are both continuous and both have continuous derivatives for $x_0 \leq x \leq x_1<$.  Then, for $x_0\le  x\le x_1$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}t  = f\big(x,b(x)\big) \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} b(x) - f\big(x,a(x)\big) \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} a(x) + \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,t) \,\mathrm{d}t \tag{1}"$$

It's overkill to try to apply this to your question since your integrand $\frac{1}{1 + \ln(t)}$ only depends on one variable, but it can still be done. Applied correctly you get
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left (\int_{1}^{e^{x}}\frac{1}{1 + \ln(t)}\,\mathrm{d}t \right) &= \frac{1}{1 + \ln(e^x)}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} e^x -\underbrace{ \frac{1}{1 + \ln(1)} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} (1)}_{0} + \int_{1}^{e^x}\underbrace{\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{1}{1 + \ln(t)}}_{0} \,\mathrm{d}t\\
& = \frac{e^x}{1+x}
\end{align}

---

What's happening here? In reality, differentiation under the integral sign is a generalization of the [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus). To see why, assume that we have $a(x) =a$ where $a$ is some constant and $f(x,t) = f(t)$ as in your question. i.e, that the lower bound is just a number and the integrand only depends on one variable. Plugging these conditions into $(1)$ we get:
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left (\int_{a}^{b(x)}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t \right) 
&= f\big(b(x)\big) \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} b(x) - \underbrace{f\big(a\big) \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} a }_{0}+ \int_{a}^{b(x)}\underbrace{\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(t)}_{0} \,\mathrm{d}t\\
& = f\big(b(x)\big) \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} b(x) \tag{2}
\end{align}
because $a$ being a constant implies $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} a =0$ and since $f$ doesn't depend on $x$ we get $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(t)=0$. But recalling the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) we notice that the RHS is *exactly* the derivative of $F(b(x))$ where $F(x)$ is an antiderivative of $f(x)$. But this is just a consequence of the FTC since
\begin{align}
&\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \underbrace{\int_{a}^{x}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t}_{F(x)} =F'(x) =f(x) \tag{FTC}\\
\mathbin{\implies}&\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \underbrace{\int_{a}^{\color{green}{b(x)}}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t}_{F(\color{green}{b(x)})} =\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} F(b(x)) \overset{\color{blue}{\text{Chain rule}}}{ =}F'(b(x))b'(x) \overset{\color{blue}{(\text{FTC})}}{=} f\big(b(x)\big)\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} b(x)\end{align}
which is exactly the same result we got in $(2)$, but this time we only used the more simple tools of the FTC and the chain rule to get the result.

---

tl;dr, you were attempting to use differentiation under the integral sign but didn't apply the theorem correctly. This method is overkill because differentiation under the integral sign is a generalization of the FTC for multivariable functions, but since your integral is dependent on only one variable the problem is solvable using only the FTC and the chain rule.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That makes sense. What happens in the case where there is a function of x in both limits. Such as $F(x)=$$\int_{x^{-1}}^{x^{0.5}}sin(t^2)$ $dt$? Normally, I have been taught to split this up into two integrals, but it is difficult to find a constant between the limits to split this one up RobertLee @Ryang

Comment: @FD_bfa, the constant you choose doesn't need to be between the limits of integration, it can be _any_ constant in the region where the function is integrable (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1316543/695196)). You can also see this directly from the equation $(\text{FTC})$ above. Notice that when you take the derivative of $\int_a^x f(t) \mathrm{d}t$ the result is $f(x)$ which _doesn't_ depend on what the value of $a$ is. As long as the integral $\int_a^x f(t) \mathrm{d}t$ is defined then $a$ can be any constant, and you'll still get the correct result after differentiating.